# Mapbox & Angular Iframe doens't work on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, iframe, leaflet, mapbox

I have deployed Angular to my Codigniter project and also I have deployed MapBox Leaflet to it as part of my project, but it doesn't work on Firefox, what I have done I used the scope and angular object inside the iFrame I use to load the mapbox map view. It works seamlessly on other browsers, but it doesn't work on Firefox.

This is the error I get on my Console

WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
angular.min.js (line 206)
TypeError: a is null

```
<iframe width="100%" height="600px" src="URL/ADDRESS/TO/MAP/WHERE/I/REUSE/ANGULAR/AND/SCOPE/AGAIN" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.js'>
        https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        " type="text/javascript">
        https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/mapbox-directions.js/v0.4.0/mapbox.directions.css' type='text/css' />
        " />

```
</head>
<body class="plugin-mapbox-driving-direction-mapview">
    <section class="">
        <div class="">
            <div id='map'></div>
            <div id='inputs'></div>
            <div id='errors'></div>
            <div id='directions'><div id='routes'></div><div id='instructions'></div></div>

            <script>
                var angular = window.parent.angular,
                    scope = window.parent.angular.element(window.frameElement).scope(),
                    initialization = true;

                //console.log("angular", angular, "angular");
                //console.log("scope", scope, "scope");

                var startCoordinates = scope.__route[0],
                    endCoordinates = scope.__route[1];

                var startLocation = {
                        lat: angular.isDefined(startCoordinates.lat) ? startCoordinates.lat : null,
                        lng: angular.isDefined(startCoordinates.lng) ? startCoordinates.lng : null,
                        loc: scope.pinOriginLocation
                    },
                    endLocation = {
                        lat: angular.isDefined(endCoordinates.lat) ? endCoordinates.lat : null,
                        lng: angular.isDefined(endCoordinates.lng) ? endCoordinates.lng : null,
                        loc: scope.pinDestinationLocation
                    },
                    origin =  {
                        type: 'Feature',
                        geometry: {
                            type: 'Point',
                            coordinates: [startLocation.lng, startLocation.lat]
                        },
                        properties: {
                            name: startLocation.loc
                        }
                    },
                    destination =  {
                        type: 'Feature',
                        geometry: {
                            type: 'Point',
                            coordinates: [endLocation.lng, endLocation.lat]
                        },
                        properties: {
                            name: endLocation.loc
                        }
                    };

                L.mapbox.accessToken = "<?php echo $this->config->item('mapbox_api_accesstoken'); ?>";

                var __journey = scope.__journey;
                var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {zoomControl: false});

                map.attributionControl.setPosition('bottomleft');

                var directions = L.mapbox.directions();
                var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions).addTo(map);
                var directionsRoutesControl = L.mapbox.directions.routesControl('routes', directions).addTo(map);
                var directionsInputControl = L.mapbox.directions.inputControl('inputs', directions).addTo(map);
                var directionsErrorsControl = L.mapbox.directions.errorsControl('errors', directions).addTo(map);
                var directionsInstructionsControl = L.mapbox.directions.instructionsControl('instructions', directions).addTo(map);
                var wayPoints = [];
                if(angular.isDefined(scope.__journey.__route) && scope.__journey.__route.length > 2) {
                    for(var i in scope.__journey.__route) {
                        if(scope.__journey.__route.length <= 20 || (wayPoints.length <= 20 && Number(i)%(Math.round(scope.__journey.__route.length / 20)) == 0))
                            wayPoints.push(L.latLng(scope.__journey.__route[i].latitude,scope.__journey.__route[i].longitude));
                    }
                }

                console.log("wayPoints", wayPoints, "wayPoints");

                setQuery(startLocation, true, origin, endLocation, true, destination, wayPoints);
                //directions.setOrigin(origin, true).setDestination(destination, true).query(undefined, false);

                scope.$watch("pinOriginLocation", function(newval, oldval) {
                    if(angular.isDefined(newval) && newval.length >= 20 && newval !== oldval) {
                        startCoordinates = scope.getCordinates(newval);

                        startLocation = {
                            lat: angular.isDefined(startCoordinates.lat) ? startCoordinates.lat : null,
                            lng: angular.isDefined(startCoordinates.lng) ? startCoordinates.lng : null,
                            loc: scope.pinOriginLocation
                        };

                        origin =  {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Point',
                                coordinates: [startLocation.lng, startLocation.lat]
                            },
                            properties: {
                                name: startLocation.loc
                            }
                        };

                        initialization = false;
                        setQuery(startLocation, undefined, origin, endLocation, undefined, destination, wayPoints);
                        //directions.setOrigin(origin).setDestination(destination).query(undefined, false);
                    }
                });

                scope.$watch("pinDestinationLocation", function(newval, oldval) {
                    if(angular.isDefined(newval) && newval.length >= 20 && newval !== oldval) {
                        endCoordinates = scope.getCordinates(newval);

                        endLocation = {
                            lat: angular.isDefined(endCoordinates.lat) ? endCoordinates.lat : null,
                            lng: angular.isDefined(endCoordinates.lng) ? endCoordinates.lng : null,
                            loc: scope.pinDestinationLocation
                        };

                        destination =  {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Point',
                                coordinates: [endLocation.lng, endLocation.lat]
                            },
                            properties: {
                                name: endLocation.loc
                            }
                        };

                        initialization = false;
                        setQuery(startLocation, undefined, origin, endLocation, undefined, destination, wayPoints);
                        //directions.setOrigin(origin).setDestination(destination).query(undefined, false);
                    }
                });

                function suggestLocation(event, element) {
                    var el = $(element);

                    if(el.val().length >= 8 && event.keyCode == 32) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type        : "POST",
                            url         : siteVars.ajaxUrl+"webservice/lookupAddress",
                            datatype    : "html",
                            data        : {
                                "code"      : siteVars.csrfHash,
                                "address"   : el.val()
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                lookup = [];

                                if(!angular.equals(data, "")) {
                                    data = JSON.parse(data);

                                    for(var i in data) {
                                        if(typeof data[i].location != 'undefined')
                                            lookup.push(data[i].location);
                                    }

                                    displaySuggestion(el, lookup);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

                function displaySuggestion(element, lookup) {
                    var attr = element.attr("id") + "DataList";
                    var html = "";

                    $("#"+attr).remove();

                    if(lookup.length > 0) {

                        for(var i in lookup)
                            html += "<div onclick='selectSuggestion(\""+element.attr("id")+"\", \""+lookup[i]+"\")' class='autocomplete-suggestion' data-index='"+i+"'>"+lookup[i]+"</div>";

                        html = "<div class='autocomplete-suggestions' id='"+attr+"'>"+html+"</div>";
                        $(html).insertAfter(element);
                    }
                };

                function selectSuggestion(element, suggestion) {
                    var el = $("#"+element);
                    el.val(suggestion);
                    $("#"+el.attr("id")+"DataList").remove();

                    if(el.attr("id") == "mapbox-directions-origin-input")
                        directions.setOrigin(suggestion);

                    if(el.attr("id") == "mapbox-directions-destination-input")
                        directions.setDestination(suggestion);

                    if(directions.queryable()) {
                        initialization = false;
                        directions.query({proximity: map.getCenter()}, false);
                    }
                }

                function setQuery(startLocation, startLocationStatus, origin, endLocation, endLocationStatus, destination, wayPoints) {
                    if(!angular.isDefined(startLocation.loc) || angular.equals(startLocation.loc, "") || angular.equals(startLocation.loc, null))
                        directions.setOrigin(L.latLng(startLocation.lat, startLocation.lng), true);
                    else
                        directions.setOrigin(origin, true);

                    if(!angular.isDefined(endLocation.loc) || angular.equals(endLocation.loc, "") || angular.equals(endLocation.loc, null))
                        directions.setDestination(L.latLng(endLocation.lat, endLocation.lng), true);
                    else
                        directions.setDestination(destination, true);

                    if(angular.isDefined(wayPoints) && wayPoints.length > 0)
                        directions.setWaypoints(wayPoints);
                        //L.Routing.control({waypoints:wayPoints}).addTo(map);

                    console.log("wayPoints", wayPoints, "wayPoints");

                    return directions.query(undefined, false);
                }

            </script>
        </div>
        <?=$this->load->view("subviews/libraries_link")?>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Without any errors or the relevant code in a minimal example on Plunker or JSFiddle, everybody would just be guessing. So i bet you're not going to get any answer unless you put a little more effort into your question.

Comment: Hope that amendment helps me get some working responses. Thanks for your attention @iH8